# Sample data with different dimensions in SVM

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, svm, libsvm

I'm planning to evaluate shooting performance with SVM.  Each person shoots 3 to 10 times. For each time of shooting, I can get wind speed, shooting score, distance, and I will tell SVM if this person is qualified in shooting. I hope to feed all these data into SVM, and after training, let SVM can judge if a person is qualified in shooting with his shooting performance.

The problem is, for each person, the shooting times is different, 3 to 10 times, which means the dimension is different for each row of sample data in SVM.

Now I'm planning to use 10*3 dimensions for each person's data(one row data for one person), if his shooting times is less than 10, I will fill all the blanks with -1.

Does it work to fill empty dimensions with -1?

Answer (score 0):

SVMs doesn't seem to be a very good approach here.
The problem is, that your *hits* are dependent on wind-speed and distance. This means, that these values are input values (and have to be because shooting-accuracy is highly dependent on the wind; someone could be lucky with the wind and get above-average scores), which your SVM is trained on. But this also means, that these inputs are needed during prediction time. So how do you want to evaluate the shooting-qualification. You could only evaluate the shooting-qualification dependent on wind and co.

Of course you could predict with all observed wind and distance values and blend your results, but this might be inefficient and you also would want to get probabilities out of the SMV which is another thing which is quite hard (supported by many libs; but probabilities out of a SVM are not that precise).

*If you want to tackle it like this*, then you would train with the samples looking like this:

- sample 0: [shooter_id, wind, distance, 1]  # 1 = hit
- sample 1: [shooter_id, wind, distance, 0]  # 0 = miss

This means, that each shot is one sample! The SVM will predict hit/miss for given input variables or probabilities if you switched them on.

In theory, this whole problem is about modelling the covariance, which is introduced by the variables wind & distance, to normalize the shooting-accuracy on enviromental factors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you misunderstood me. I want SVM to evaluate if a shooter is a qualified shooter or not, according to his shooting performance. My problem is the shooting times for each shooter is different, someone may shoot 3 times, others may shoot more, so the dimension for training sample is different.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. And it seems, that you don't have much machine-learning experience.

Comment: Ok, let me describe my problem in a easier way. I only want SVM judge If a shooter is qualified by his shooting scores. First I feed SVM data like this: sample 0 :[score1, score2, score3] # 1 = qualified shooter.   sample 1:[score1, score2, score3, score4, score5] # 0 = unqualified. sample 2: [score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6] # 1 = qualified.

Comment: Since my comment is too long, I have to make it an answer. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me describe my problem in an easier way. I only want SVM judge If a shooter is qualified by his shooting scores. First I feed SVM data like this:

```
sample 0 :[score1, score2, score3] # 1 = qualified shooter.  
sample 1:[score1, score2, score3, score4, score5] # 0 = unqualified. 
sample 2: [score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6] # 1 = qualified.
```

Since the shooting times is different for each shooter, so the dimension of each sample is different. Could I format all the samples to 10 dimensions like this?:

```
sample 0 : [score1, score2, score3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # 1 = qualified. 
sample 1 : [score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] # 0 = unqualified
```

This time I ignore wind speed and disctance data because that have nothing to do with my question, my question is about dimensions. All the samples have different dimensions (3 to 10), Could I format the all the samples to 10 dimensions and fill the blanks with -1?

Comment: There are many issues: 1) the only thing to learn is a threshold/ratio/count (because there is no other information). Why you don't just count and set this threshold. Much simpler than SVM. 2) While your filling is possible, i don't think i will work good (heavy parameter tuning might be needed). One interesting thing is, that different orders might give different results. 3) All in all that is a very very bad example for SVM-usage...

Comment: I just offered a simpler example to make my problem understandable. In fact, there are at least 3 parameters in each score, and I judge if each sample is qualified or not with my feeling. I hope SVM can do this judgement for me. So you don't think it's an easy job for SVM?